# javascript svg onmouseover effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

how do I have popups boxes when moving the mouse over the circle?

I have been trying hours to figure this out. Is it possible to only work on the code in javascript file here without changing anything in the html file?

javascript:

```
 svg.selectAll("circle")
 .data(sales)
 .enter()

 .....//other circle attributes

 .onmouseover = function(d,i){
    alert("haha");
}
```

Even the simple alert function didn't work. Nothing showed up when I moved over the circle. this is my first day learning data visualization please help out a newbie thanks!

Comment: This is d3 correct? If so add the `d3` tag.

Comment: is this a d3 question - perhaps worth mentioning, and tagging as such.

Comment: sorry about that. yes it is d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind event handler by using [selection.**on**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on)

```
 svg.selectAll("circle")
 .data(sales)
 .enter()

 .....//other circle attributes

 .on('mouseover', function(){
     d3.select(this).style('fill', 'red');
  })
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sj8gLopz/**

Comment: maybe it's too advanced for me but could you explain a little bit about how this is different from my original solution? I got that one by searching "mouseover effect javascript" online and it seems like others' suggestions in creating an mouseover effect.                                     Also, if I wanted to have a popup description box after moving the mouse over, what should I put in the function? the description would be relevant to the specific data object. So should I put the (d,i) back into the functions arguments? thanks!!

Comment: @whales The reason you have to use d3 `on` method is to allow [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). Under the hood, d3 is using plain old javascript event listeners as you can see [here in the source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/5b981a18db32938206b3579248c47205ecc94123/src/selection/on.js#L53).